# error retrieving image is failure callback camera plugin - Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using the [camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md) in my project calling it this way:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoCaptureSucc, onPhotoCaptureFail,
    {
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    });


function onPhotoCaptureSucc(img) {
    alert("onPhotoCaptureSucc" + img);
}
function onPhotoCaptureFail(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

but it is always failing and I am getting this message "error retrieving image" which is useless.

How to get more info about the reason why is failing?
What could be the next step?

In a stand-alone project (having only this plugin) it works properly.

I am using Windows Phone 8.

Comment: looking into the source code, it's an IOException, look into the ouputModifiedBitmap https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/CameraLauncher.java

Comment: @jcesarmobile, thanks but I am using wp8

Comment: then on https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/wp/Camera.cs the line 329 is calling the error callback, try printing the exception right before calling the error callback

Comment: Yes, I am debugging there

Comment: @jcesarmobile, FYI I solved it by upgrading cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging the plugin source code I noticed an exception cause by a C# class present in cordovalib.

I solved by upgrading from 3.6 to cordova 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Windows phone 8 doesn't allow to take picture or videos from gallery using cordova-camera plugin . i even tried to make a plugin for that but it didn't worked..!!!